# How to programmatically set selection on a jTree child

Tags: java, parent-child, jtree, treepath

I've read through a bunch of questions already asked but haven't see an solid answer yet.  I'm trying to set the selection on a jTree in an attempt to create a sort of API for my Java project.  I can set selection on a parent node easily with say:
myTree.setSelection(1);

Having trouble with any leafs off child nodes.  I've have a walk function and I'm looking for a specific string in it.  I've managed to return a Object[] when I reach the node with the string I'm looking for.  But I can't convert it to a Treepath to use myTree.setSelectionPath(path).  Can anyone help out with this?  I appreciate it.

```
//My call
TreeModel model = jTree1.getModel();
        Object getNode = myWalk(model);
        jTree1.setSelectionPath((TreePath) getNode);
        //this throw an error stating that Object[] can't be converted to a path.  

public Object[] myWalk(TreeModel model, String s, String t){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode child;
        TreeNode[] returnPath = null;
        int childrenCount = root.getChildCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++){
            child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) root.getChildAt(i);
            if(child.toString().equals(s)){
                System.out.println(child.toString());
                int secondChildCount = child.getChildCount();
                DefaultMutableTreeNode secondLevelChild;
                for(int y = 0; y < secondChildCount; y++){
                    secondLevelChild = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) child.getChildAt(y);
                    if(secondLevelChild.toString().equals(t)){
                        System.out.println(secondLevelChild.toString());
                        returnPath = secondLevelChild.getPath();
                        //returnPath = new TreePath(new Object[] {root.toString(), child.toString(), secondLevelChild.toString()});
                    }
                }

            }


        }
        return returnPath;
    }
```

Comment: There's a setSelectionPath that takes a TreePath.  Since your scanning the tree depth first, you can simply recusrively build up the TreePath.

Answer (score 2):

So the solution ended up being simple.  I just need to create a new TreePath with and Object array (which I wasn't doing).

So it would look like:

```
TreeModel model = jTree1.getModel();
Object[] getNode = Walk(model, "sports", "basketball");
TreePath tPath = new TreePath(getNode);
jTree1.setSelectionPath(tPath);
```

Comment: But if you want to select only child node of ThreePath (`tPathParent`), which you know, you can just call `TreePath tPath = tPathParent.pathByAddingChild(childNode); jTree1.setSelectionPath(tPath);`. childNode must be of same class (as tPathParent elements), and it must have correct realization of `equals` and `hashCode` methods for inner comparation in `TreeModel`.